# What does shot noise in color images look like?

Tags: digital, color, noise

I can find examples of [shot noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shot_noise) in monochrome images, but I can't find any examples in color images.  What does shot noise in color images look like?

Comment: It looks pretty much the same: random. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Exactly the same.** Both CCD and CMOS sensors - with the exception of Foveon sensors - are achromatic. Color is created by an array of color filters in front of the sensor, so the shot-noise is the same, only you tint each pixel Red, Green or Blue. A few rare cameras also use Emerald tint and some leave one sub-pixel achromatic.

Comment: Can you provide examples, assuming a Bayer array?

Comment: @DragonLord - Look at any ISO-noise test. There is your example.

Comment: Look at an ISO noise test as long as Noise-Reduction was turned off, which is not possible on each camera. Here is an older one from a Nikon D3: http://blog.neocamera.com/?p=244